# UWP/C# How to Save a Comboboxitem Selection As a String In Sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml, combobox, uwp

I've successfully set a List as the ItemsSource for a Combobox, it is showing the items I expect it to. Also able to set the default SelectedItem by specifying the index. But I'm having trouble in saving the selected item to a string in Sqlite. When displaying the saved Sqlite value it just shows the class name. I tried saving just the index instead and right index is displayed later on, so I do think I'm getting the right item, but its clearly not the right content when I save the actual item. Just learning for a few weeks now... Can anyone suggest a conversion or other way around it?

XAML:

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="boxMethod"
              Header="Payment Method:"
              Width="200"
              SelectionChanged="boxMethod_SelectionChanged">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding NickName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

C# main:

```
    this.boxMethod.ItemsSource  = payMethod.GetPayMethods();

    transaction.PmtMethod       = Convert.ToString(boxMethod.SelectedValue);
```

C# to display elsewhere:

```
    txtPmtMethod.Text   = Convert.ToString(selectedTransaction.PmtMethod);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you debug at the second line of your C# Main you will notize that PmtMethod is the classname. boxMethod.SelectedValue is an instance of your class and if you cast it to a string you'll get the classname.
You could cast it to an instance of your class with (MyClass)boxMethod.SelectedValue and then call the property which contains the value you want to save.

Just as an info. You should learn about MVVM. It's a pattern which describes how to write WPF applications.

Comment: Thanks. PmtMethod may be highlighted as a class above, but its just a string field. Not sure if your extra info applies since its not a class. Appreciate the help...

Comment: That's not what I tried to explain. I'm talking about boxMethod.SelectedValue. Debug and have a look what's the value of this. It'll be an instance of a class. And if you cast a class as a string you'll get the classname per default.